# When does objective-C call the cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to iOS development, and study about Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE, Bluetooth 4.0) for IOS.

I am try to add the 10 data to `tableView`.

From the log , it will run **`10 time`** for **`cellForRowAtIndexPath`**.

**`The question is :`**

How the objective-c know it have to run **`10 time`** for **`cellForRowAtIndexPath`** ?

Is it according to the `numberOfRowsInSection` ?

Comment: Objective-C doesn't load anything it is iOS that loads cells

Comment: @Pawan-Systematix strictly spoken it is not even iOS that calls anything here. It is the cocoa touch framework.

Comment: Actually, neither of you is correct.  It's the fairies behind the glass that do it.

Comment: Thank goodness you didn't ask about `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. That one's even more complicated......      : )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called every time when a cell comes to view.

Don't expect it to be called a certain times nor expect any specific sequence.

Example: 
There is one section only with 15 rows. Therefore the table will have 15 cells in total - from the user's point of view. `numberOfRowsInSection` will return 15.

Let's say that 10 of them are visible on an iPhone 5 and 9 of them are visible on an iPhone 4. 
At start `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called 9 times on an iPhone 4 and 10 times on an iPhone 5.

Let's continue with the iPhone 5. The user now scrolls to the bottom of the table. 5 more cells come into view. Then `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called 5 times. 
BTW 4 of these cells that disappeared earlier can and will be reused. (given that all cells are of the same type and reuse-identifier)

So far `cellForRowAtIndexPath` was called once for each cell.

Now the user scrolls up again to the top of the table. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is now called again for cell of row 4, 3, 2, 1 and 0.

So far `cellForRowAtIndexPath` was called 20 times for 15 cells.

Now the user ...

Comment: Actually, it's called *just before* the cell comes into view.

Comment: As for the sequence, yes, it is called first. Naturally because the UI Object to be displayed, the `UITableViewCell`, is created within and returned to the framework. But that happens exactly then, when the cell is required and about to be displayed. It is not called in advance.

Comment: The `tableView` will run the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `numberOfRowsInSection` by itself if I have set the `tableView` to `dataSource` and `delegate` ?

Comment: @Wun, I am not 100% positive because I never did that myself. However, if no dataSource or delegate are set at all, then I don't expect it to be called at all. I'd expect the framework (here the table view) to check for null first, then to double check, whether the delegate or data source does conforms to the protocol in charge and then whether the related methods are responded to by the delegate and data source.

Answer (score 0):

**cellForRowAtIndexPath** will be call, Whenever the view **displaying** or **changing** the tableView.

For your clear understand put a breakpoint in cellForRowAtIndexPath method then run, you'll know that how it called.